# I sleep with the stars - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, science

I sleep with the stars,

I could land in your bed,

I can move square to square,

I'm a ____________.

Comment: Does the object rhyme with bed to complete the rhyme?

Comment: @beastlygerbil It does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're a

> Horse head

I sleep with the stars

> Horsehead nebula

I could land in your bed

> from the movie Godfather

I can move square to square

> In chess, the Knight piece is usually a horse head

and it completes the rhyme!

Comment: Make the first word a possessive and it fits the metre too.

Comment: I'll make you an answer you can't downvote...

Comment: @kayzeroshort A fine answer.  Well done mate.  +1

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's what I had in mind.  +1

Comment: @CodeNewbie Clever! :) +1